# Any suggestion for regex search within several hundred million texts (stored in MongoDB)

Tags: java, regex, mongodb, solr, lucene

Here is the scenario:

- Text fields are stored in MongoDB currently;
- Fields are larger than 1KB on average, thus cannot be indexed;
- Need to perform exact phrase searches on text fields;

The requirements for search are the following:

- Should be able to use placeholders/wildcards for (any) single or multiple characters (like `?`,`*` or `(.)(.*)`);
- Should be able to indicate the position of the phrase within the searched text (beginning, anywhere, end: `phrase%`, `%phrase%`, `%phrase`);
- Results should be exact matches.

What I have tried already:

- Fields are not indexable, since mongodb has 1KB limit on indexed fields;
- Splitting text into 1KB chunks, regex is still slow and is not using index when searched phrase is not (^phrase);
- MongoDB full text search - not sure if i can query for positions and exact matches for phrases;
- Tried to use Solr, no luck (with enabling ComplexPhraseQueryParser);
- ComplexPhraseQueryParser (which supports wildcards) is built into lucene but don't know how to indicate the position of the searched phrase within the text and how to get only exact matches;

Current possible solution is to just keep the text fields in RDBMS (MySQL, is it a good idea? No sure about varchar and text field indexing limitations) and use the LIKE operator, but I'd love to hear some suggestions:

- It would be great to have it all in MongoDB and use it's built-in capabilities;
- OR use solr, since it will be used for other search capabilities, is reliable, scalable, etc.;
- OR use lucene, same as solr, but will have to deal with scalability, replication and other issues on my own;
- Any other option?

**UPDATE:**

I have come to conclusion that current MongoDB version is not capable to fulfill the requirements so moved on in solr direction a bit. This is what I've got so far:

- Solr queries work (`/.*sear.* ph.ase.*/`);
- Regex searches for the beginning of the text are super fast as expected (`/sear.* ph.ase.*/`);
- Others, middle and end (`/.*sear.* ph.ase.*/`, `/.*sear.* ph.ase/`) are a bit slow (searching within 200,000 documents in solr takes arround 900ms on my workstation);

Searched solr field type is:

```
<fieldType name="text_keyword_lowercase" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
 <analyzer>
  <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
 </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Any suggestions on this?

Thanks!

Comment: MongoDBs text search is still a preview release, and not intended for production. If you can somehow bend MongoDb to your will and get it to perform the queries you need, I expect performance to be poor. You should look at Lucene either with Solr or ElasticSearch more closely, and maybe return with a more specific targeted question if you cannot figure out a particular aspect of implementation.

Comment: I totally agree. I was expecting that someone has an experience with similar requirements and would suggest an option.

Comment: @WiredPrairie I have 0 experience with Solr/ElasticSearch, do you think/know ElasticSearch is better fitted/could provide better performance in this case? Thanks!

Comment: Without testing, it's hard to tell. But, I don't believe that a MongoDB 2.4 solution will perform as well.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that:

> regex is still slow and is not using index when searched phrase is not (^phrase)

So might it be possible to force it to use that regex always to improve performance?
What I mean is, inject at the beginning of every search query `(^.\*)` so the full regex looks like: `(^.\*phrase)`

You'd have to check for `^` at the start of the search phrase of course, and if found either strip it out first or don't inject `(^.\*)`.